# How to get a specified character of a string

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I would like to know, how to get a specified character of a string in MS-Access 2010. The exact thing I would like to do is to get the 2nd character of a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access doesn't support Standard SQL's `SUBSTRING`, but there's a similar function, `MID`:

```
MID(col, 2,1)
```

Comment: `Mid()` is a VBA function, but you can use these in queries.

Comment: Mid() is not just VBA, it also works outside of Access with a connection to the Jet/ACE database.